# Android switching between PreferenceScreens

Tags: android, preferences

I have a PreferencesScreen, that has some Preferences and a sub-screen. It looks like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen android:key="root">

    <Preference android:key="first" />

    <PreferenceScreen android:key="subScreen" />
        <Preference android:key="second" />
        <Preference android:key="third" />
    </PreferenceScreen>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

When user clicks the subscreen, he is moved to the subscreen view. Now I want to redirect the user to "root" preference screen when he clicks on "second" or "third". I don't seem to find the right API to either close the subscreen, or focus the previous one. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preference subscreen is displayed as a dialog, in your case it would be enough to dismiss the dialog representing appropriate `PreferenceScreen`. Insert the following snippet into `onPreferenceClick()` method of `OnPreferenceClickListener` you probably set for "second" and "third" preferences to close the dialog:

```
PreferenceScreen ps = (PreferenceScreen)PrefsActivity.this.getPreferenceScreen()
    .findPreference("subScreen");
ps.getDialog().dismiss();
```

where `PrefsActivity` is the enclosing instance of `PreferenceActivity` that is used in your application.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you have bare `Preference` elements in the first place. Off the top of my head, I cannot think of anywhere in Settings where the user would encounter your desired behavior, so what you are trying to do is likely to be unexpected. Also, I recommend you start to move away from nested `PreferenceScreen` elements, as the new direction is `PreferenceFragments` for Honeycomb onward.

That being said, try `setPreferenceScreen()` on `PreferenceActivity` and see if it gives you what you need.

Comment: I have cleaned up the snippet above just for brevity. The whole source contained more detail that is irrelevant to my question.